# Use replaceWith on specific element value with Jquery variable

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I think this is a simple syntax issue that I can't find. I'm trying to use replaceWith to replace an  element with another value on JSON post response.

I'm able to get it working if I hard code the returned ID value in my a tag. But can't append the jQuery variable instead. Here is code.

This example below works, you can see the `data-id` attribute is hard-coded `=1`.

```
    if (intention_id == id) {
      $('[data-id=1]').replaceWith(new_intention);
    } else {
      $('#intentions').append(new_intention);
    }
```

This example below doesn't work, you can see I'm trying to use a jquery variable called `intention_id` (which I know is a good variable because it works in the if statement right above it.

```
    if (intention_id == id) {
      $('[data-id= +intention_id]').replaceWith(new_intention);
    } else {
      $('#intentions').append(new_intention);
    }
```

I think I just have the syntax wrong for appending a jQuery variable for an `[attribute=x]` situation.

Comment: You're adding the string literal `+intention_id` to the `data-id` attribute. You should put it between quotes: `$('[data-id=' + intention_id + ']')`.

Comment: @nbokmans thats the ticket! nice. thank you very much.